# Endable moodle tour via config or database

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

Is it possible to enable a specific tour in Moodle (e.g. Welcome) for a specific theme (e.g. Boost) via the database or the config.php?

Answer (score 1):

Not via `config.php` - there is an option for `forced_plugin_settings` but I don't think this will work for your request

https://docs.moodle.org/402/en/Configuration_file#Forcing_the_value_of_admin_settings

You could update the database via SQL, but you will need to JSON encode the data

The theme filter is in the column `configdata`

eg:

```
SELECT configdata
FROM mdl_tool_usertours_tours
```

Look for `""theme"":[""boost""]`

Or you could set the theme filter via PHP

```
$tour = tourinstance::instance($tourid]);
$tour->set_filter_values('theme', ['boost']);
```